# Abbreviate a list in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

How can I abbreviate a list so that

```
WHERE id IN ('8893171511',

'8891227609',
'8884577292',
'886790275X',
.
.
.)
```

becomes

```
WHERE id IN (name of a group/list)
```

Comment: Store the list in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the list is large, I would create a temporary table and store the list there.

That way you can `ANALYZE` the temporary table and get accurate estimates.

Answer (score 1):

The list really would have to appear somewhere.  From the point of view of your code being maintainable and reusable, you could represent the list in a CTE:

```
WITH id_list AS (
    SELECT '8893171511' AS id UNION ALL
    SELECT '8891227609' UNION ALL
    SELECT '8884577292' UNION ALL
    SELECT '886790275X'
)

SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM cte);
```

If you have a persistent need to do this, then maybe the CTE should become a bona fide table somewhere in your database.

Edit: Using the Horse's suggestion, we can tidy up the CTE to the following:

```
WITH id_list (id) AS (
VALUES
    ('8893171511'),
    ('8891227609'),
    ('8884577292'),
    ('886790275X')
)
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Do you know some way to use a `VALUES` clause and also control the name of the columns (so that they don't just become `column1`, `column2`, etc.) ?

Answer (score 0):

The temp table and CTE answers suggested will do.

Just wanted to bring another approach, that will work if you use PGAdmin for querying (not sure about workbench) and represent your data in a "stringy" way.

```
set setting.my_ids = '8893171511,8891227609';
select current_setting('setting.my_ids');

drop table if exists t;
create table t ( x text);
insert into t select 'some value';
insert into t select '8891227609';


select *
from t
where x = any( string_to_array(current_setting('setting.my_ids'), ',')::text[]);
```

Comment: It is not pgAdmin specifically and it could be simplified: `set setting.my_ids = '{8893171511,8891227609}';` and then `... where x = any(current_setting('setting.my_ids')::text[]);`